# Exponential(1) distribution of Normally distributed X and Y

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $X_1,X_2,X_3,X_4,X_5$ be a random sample from the uniform pdf: $f(x)= 1$, $0<x<1$ zero otherwise. Show that $\ln X_i$ has Exponential($1$) distribution for $i=1,2,3,4,5$.

Solution: Let $Y=\ln X$ with support of $x<0$, thus $$G(y)= P(Y\le y)= P(\ln X\le y)=P(X \ge e^y)= 1-P(X \le e^y)= 1-e^y$$ To get the pdf of y, $g(y)=G'(y)= -e^y$ but this is not equal to Exponential ($1$).

Please help.

Comment: "Since the support of Y is negative values..": why does this matter?

Comment: just to illustrate the change in inequality

Comment: should the inequality change?

Comment: Also, the exponential distribution is supported on $[0, +\infty)$. As you said, $\ln(X)$ takes negative values. Maybe you are interested in $Y=-\ln(X)$..

Answer (score 1):

In your answer the equality $\ldots=P(\ln X\le y)\overset{??}=P(X \color{red}{\ge} e^y)=\ldots$ is not justified. The function $\exp$ is monotone increasing and therefore it's application does not justify the reversal of the inequality sign. Moreover as it is the exercise is not correct, since $Y$  has not the appropriate support. But it works if we assume that you mean $Y=-\ln X$ instead. In more detail:

---

Since $X\in (0,1)$ you have that $Y=\ln X \in (-\infty, 0)$. Therefore as it is mentioned in the comments $Y$ cannot have the exponential distribution, since the latter has support $(0,+\infty)$. Therefore assuming that $Y=-\ln X$ (to overcome this problem) with $Y \in (0, +\infty)$, then for $y>0$ you have that $$\begin{align*}G(y)&=P(Y\le y)=P(-\ln X \le y)=P(\ln X \ge -y)=P(X\ge e^{-y})\\[0.2cm]&=1-P(X\le e^{-y})=1-F(e^{-y})\end{align*}$$ Thus, by differentiating you find that $$g(y)=\frac{\partial}{\partial y}G(y)=\frac{\partial}{\partial y}(1-F(e^{-y}))=-f(e^{-y})\cdot (e^{-y})'=1\cdot e^{-y}=e^{-y}$$ which is indeed the pdf of the exponential distribution with parameter $λ=1$.